# JSONP - Access-Control-Allow-Origin and MIME type errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I am trying to both create the Server and client side of a jsonp request, and I cannot seem to make it work.  I've looked around at numerous guides, blog posts, etc, but pretty much everyone shows only the client side.

Here's my client code

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'application/json',
    data: params,
    jsonp: 'jsonpCallback',
    url: settings.domain + '/httpext.dll?json_cc',
    success: function (data) {
        //determine the return status
    },
    error: function (response, status, error) {
        //error handling
    }
}); //end ajax
```

right now, the server is returning a hard coded value like this

```
jsonpCallback({"username":"meltingice","posts"1234});
```

My problem is that I cannot get the request and response to work together.  Currently, the response is returning application/json, so if I change my request ro expect jsonp it errors with

Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonpCallback is not defined

First off, as you can see, I have jsonpCallback defined.

Now, if I change the dataType to application/json, then I get this error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver/httpext.dll?json_cc&sid=adsfhasjdkfhajksdghjk%3Basdhg&action=SALE&ccCard=&ccNum=&ccExMM=0&ccExYYYY=0&ccCVV2=&holdersName=&totalDue=0&dueDate=11%2F19%2F2010. Origin http://localhost:59905 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

As you can see, it is not putting `callback=?` into the url.  It's rather frustrating.

How do I set up the server side so I can call it using jsonp?  What do I need for the response type?  How do I format the data returned so my client side code can pull back the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because your server is always returning a hardcoded method name and your client is using an anonymous `success` handler. This cannot work. You need to configure your server to use the method name passed as argument or it will never invoke the `success` callback at the client. So once you configure your server to take into account the `jsoncallback` query parameter you could test it like this:

```
$.getJSON(settings.domain + '/httpext.dll?json_cc&jsoncallback=?', params, function(result) {
    alert('success');
});
```

Now the server will receive a request that might look like this:

```
http://foo.com/httpext.dll?json_cc&jsoncallback=jsonp1290183992345
```

and it should respond like this:

```
jsonp1290183992345({"username":"meltingice","posts"1234});
```

with proper `Content-Type` as well obviously (`application/json`).

Comment: I've changed the code to pull in the default callback name, but I am still getting other errors.  Resource interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type application/json.

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to contribute this snippet I used in ASP.NET MVC to handle the jsoncallback.

```
    private static ActionResult GetContent(object data, string callback)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(callback))
        {
            ContentResult result = new ContentResult();
            result.ContentType = "application/json";

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            result.Content = string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, json);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
            result.Data = data;
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            return result;
        }
    }
```